# Sound not working after suspend MacBook7,1 Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound, 13.04, suspend

In sound settings, I see only a Dummy output option.  Was working prior to last Ubuntu updates.

The only way I can restore it is by booting back into OSX and then rebooting to Ubuntu.

Rebooting Ubuntu doesn't work to fix it.

I'd like a better way :)

> lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
>   00:08.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
>       Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device cb89
>       Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
>       Memory at d3280000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>       Capabilities: 
>       Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

Comment: Ok so I restarted into OSX to enable sound again, restarted.

What is usually in the sound settings is the following:
Digital Output (SPDIF)
Headphones
Analog Output

Built in Audio under all of them though it probably doesn't help much.

Comment: I tried use sudo /sbin/alsa reload and it is stuck with the below output and never finishes.

`d-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-cirrus snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-cirrus snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-page-alloc snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel update 3.8.0-21 fixed my issue

Comment: No. It did not for me. I am at 3.11.x